# Pathfinder: Create new object (retain source objects)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Pathfinder to create new objects out of existing objects, but I want to keep (one of) the source objects.

Currently I duplicate the source objects by hand before applying Pathfinder. Is there a setting in Pathfinder or another method to avoid the manual duplication step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, making a **Compound Shape**

- To create a **Compound Shape** from different pathfinder, after
  selecting both shapes, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click the Pathfinder
  option.

[image: compound shape]

[image: minus front]